# View Members Tab of a Group

Tags: 8, group

So I've had my first taste of Drupal Group, and it looks really promising so far. Now I may be missing something totally, but if my user (testuser1) is a  member of a group with 2 other members, why can I not see the **Member** tab as *testuser1*?
[image]

However, as a site admin I can see the Members Tab:
[image]

I already have enabled the Group Type permission: *View individual group members* for both members and outsiders. So my question is, how do I allow members and outsiders to view the members of that group?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have now realised that the *Members* tab I displayed above for the site admin, was actually just a tab to show the User-Group relationship, which in way no way links to the user's profile.

So I've applied a solution (which I'm happy with) using Views module. For now I'll just link to my [pastebin for this](https://pastebin.com/xLLFpA60) and explain the solution a little later.